# How to concatenate 2 action class variables in Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I have 2 variable in my action class, `id1` and `id2`. Joined by a `_`, they're used as a map key.

I am not able to retrieve the map value using this code:

```
<s:property value="%{mymap[id1_id2]}" />
```

How should I retrieve the map value?

Comment: Please provide some code; if the values are the same, and you're concatenating them the same way, and it's the same map, there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: <s:property value="%{mymap[id1_id2]}" /> or i have set 2 variable like <s:set var="id1", value=%{id1}/>  <s:set var="id2", value=%{id2}/> b ut not able to contact and get value from map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `id1_id2` in OGNL will assume the presence of a variable named `id1_id2`, since it's a perfectly legal identifier.

If you want to concatenate strings, you'd need:

```
<s:property value="%{mymap[id1 + '_' + id2]}" />
```

I'd likely create a separate variable to use as the key:

```
<s:set var="mapKey" value="%{id1 + '_' + id2}" />
<s:property value="%{mymap[#mapKey]}" />
```

Or more likely, I'd do it somewhere besides the view layer.