# How can we append 2 strings in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I need to append 2 `String` class variables using Struts 2

I tried like this

```jsp
<s:set var="Name" value="#variable1+#variable2"/>
```

but no result.

Comment: Did you try this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242704/how-to-concatenate-2-action-class-variables-in-struts-2

Comment: This `value="#variable1+#variable2"` inside set tag should work. Are you sure your variables are being initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OGNL to force evaluation of concatenation operation

```
<s:set var="Name" value="%{#variable1 + #variable2}"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense `value` attribute of set tag already takes an expression.

Answer (score 3):

it is also working.

```
<s:set var="Name" value="#variable1+''+#variable2"/>
```