# How concat a param + string in Struts value?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I have a jsp component where I pass a param to choose what the component display.
Into the this jsp, I have a Struts text:

```
<s:text name="format.money">
  <s:param name="value" value="%{#attr.correctionsItem.value}"/>&nbsp;
</s:text>
```

it works but I would like to chose as a param what this s:text display and I tried to do this:

```
<s:text name="format.money">
  <s:param name="value" value="%{#attr.correctionsItem + '.' + '#attr.value'}"/>&nbsp;
</s:text>
```

Problem with this solution,the framework tries to evaluation #attr.correctionsItem and pass it as an object because it doesn't concat the 2 parts and I get an error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Do you know how I can concat these value to give the full string as a param?

Thanks

Comment: did you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242704/how-to-concatenate-2-action-class-variables-in-struts-2) solution as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789198/how-can-we-append-2-strings-in-struts) .

Comment: Actually, I tried the second solution into my s:param but I don't want to concat 2 strings or 2 values. I try to concat the property of the object correctionsItem  to display.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how to do it:

```
<s:text name="format.money">
  <s:param name="value" value="%{#attr.correctionsItem[#attr.varCorrection]}"/>
</s:text>
```